# cordova application suddenly down after updating android webview

Tags: android, webview

I created a cordova application. It was working for last one year.Today I updated android webview in my device,suddenly app not working and UI also not rending properly.I am using cordova 5.x.

I did't face this issue before.

Some one please help me.

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome or Webview playstore Upgrade the SYSTEM will kill the cordova app(With SystemWebViewClient and SystemWebChromeClient extends Webview) and relaunches it.Helps in getting new updates of webview to 3rd party Developers.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview